# How to methodically work out stars and bars with constraints?

Tags: combinatorics

Specifically with regards to this question:

How many 6 digit numbers have the sum of their digits equal to 19?

I understand that this is essentially a stars and bars question with constraints: $1 \leq d_1 \leq 9$ and $0 \leq d_i \leq 9, i \in\{2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Can someone kindly explain how I would work this out? I particularly struggle when the constraint is less than or equal or there are 2 constraints to deal with for a single variable.